# What is the best way to redefine a function that has type ambiguity 0/0 at an isolated point?

Tags: functions, function-construction

Consider the following Green Function of wire turn producing magnetic field:

```
Br[R_, Z_, {r_, z_}]= ((z - Z) (-(((r^2 + R^2 + (z - Z)^2) EllipticE[-((
           4 r R)/((r - R)^2 + (z - Z)^2))])/(
        r^2 + 2 r R + R^2 + (z - Z)^2)) + 
       EllipticK[-((4 r R)/((r - R)^2 + (z - Z)^2))]))/(R Sqrt[(r - 
        R)^2 + (z - Z)^2])
```

It is evaluated to `Indeterminate` at `R=0`. However `Limit[Br[R,Z,{r,z}],R->0,Direction->"FromAbove"]` gives 0 as it should be.

What is the best way to modify/append the definition of `Br[R, Z, {r, z}]` to avoid this issue. Simple

```
Br[0, Z_, {r_, z_}]=0;
Br[0., Z_, {r_, z_}]=0;
```

does not always work, e.g., in case of `Br[R, Z, {r, z}]/.R->0`.

In similar cases  I also tryied

```
Br[R_, Z_, {r_, z_}]/;R>0 = ...
Br[0, Z_, {r_, z_}] = 0;
Br[0., Z_, {r_, z_}] = 0;
```

But I am not sure that this is recommended soluttion.

Answer (score 2):

```
Clear[Br]
Br[R_ /; R == 0, Z_, {r_, z_}] = 0
Br[R_ /; R != 0, Z_, {r_, z_}] = 
 Abs[Sign[R]] ((z - 
       Z) (-(((r^2 + 
              R^2 + (z - 
                 Z)^2) EllipticE[-((4 r R)/((r - R)^2 + (z - 
                    Z)^2))])/(r^2 + 2 r R + R^2 + (z - Z)^2)) + 
       EllipticK[-((4 r R)/((r - R)^2 + (z - Z)^2))]))/(R Sqrt[(r - 
          R)^2 + (z - Z)^2])

Br[0, 3, {1/2, 2}]
Br[0., 3, {1/2, 2}]
Br[R, 3, {1/2, 2}] /. R -> 0
Br[R, 3, {1/2, 2}] /. R -> 0.

(* 0 *)
(* 0 *)
(* 0 *)
(* 0 *)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try an IF statement like:

```
Br[R_, Z_, {r_, z_}] = 
 If[R == 0, 
  0, ((z - 
       Z) (-(((r^2 + 
              R^2 + (z - 
                 Z)^2) EllipticE[-((4 r R)/((r - R)^2 + (z - 
                    Z)^2))])/(r^2 + 2 r R + R^2 + (z - Z)^2)) + 
       EllipticK[-((4 r R)/((r - R)^2 + (z - Z)^2))]))/(R Sqrt[(r - 
          R)^2 + (z - Z)^2])]

Br[R, Z, {r, z}] /. R -> 0

0
```

Comment: Not sure, but `If` can be slower than `/;` .

Answer (score 1):

I'd try a series expansion at $R=0$ combined with `Piecewise`:

```
BBr[R_, Z_, {r_, z_}] = 
  Piecewise[{{Series[Br[R, Z, {r, z}], {R, 0, 1}] // FullSimplify // 
 Normal, R < 10^-12}},
            Br[R, Z, {r, z}]]
```

[image]

Maybe the condition on $R$ should depend on the other parameters and not be picked absolutely: for example, `R < 10^-12 * Z`.

Comment: Once I tested various methods. `Piecewise` was the slowest solution if I remember right.

Comment: My main point here was the use of a series expansion instead of only plugging the hole at $R=0$. You can combine this with `If` or with pattern matching or with a `Dispatch` however you prefer.

Comment: It really depends on your use case. `If` is a logical clause and may get evaluated too early; `Piecewise` is a mathematical clause and will evaluate much later.